# Post photo to Instagram - trouble with filename

Tags: android, image, android-intent, instagram

I am trying to post a photo from my application to Instagram.

`Image path`: `C:\Users\******\src\main\res\drawable\icon120x120.png`

From Instagram - Android intents:

```
String type = "image/*";
String filename = "/myPhoto.jpg";
String mediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename;
String captionText = "Posting to Instagram";

createInstagramIntent(type, mediaPath, captionText);
```

I tried changing `filename to:`

```
String filename = "C:\\Users\\*****\\src\\main\res\\drawable\\icon120x120.png"
```

But it does not work. Can someone please help?

The application simply states that the image failed to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have file `myPhoto.jpg` on your device's SD-card?

```
String filename = "C:\\Users\\*****\\src\\main\res\\drawable\\icon120x120.png"
```

This path is from your computer, not your device.

Copy your picture to SD-card first, for example via `adb push` command.